# Tesseract on VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, tesseract

I'm working on a project where OCR is used. Right now, I'm having a problem with this line of code

```
    Dim ocr As New Ocr()
    Using bmp As New Bitmap("C:\Users\BESToffshoreSERVICE\Downloads\banktest.png")
        MsgBox("asdsada")
        Dim tessocr As New tessnet2.Tesseract()
        'tessocr.Init(Nothing, "eng", False)
        'tessocr.GetThresholdedImage(bmp, Rectangle.Empty).Save("c:\temp\" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString() & ".bmp")
        '' Tessdata directory must be in the directory than this exe
        'Console.WriteLine("Multithread version")
        'ocr.DoOCRMultiThred(bmp, "eng")
        'Console.WriteLine("Normal version")
        'ocr.DoOCRNormal(bmp, "eng")
    End Using
```

The line that gives me an error is this
`Dim tessocr As New tessnet2.Tesseract()`
if I remove that line the msgbox will display. Any idea why this happens?
I have added tessnet2 reference, and I got this code in C#.

OK. Somehow I managed to solved it. The problem was :
1. I was targeting a x86 build, while the dll requires x64. Solved it by changing x86 to Any CPU. 
2. It requires .Net Framework 2.0.Changed from 4.0 to 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Imports statement to the top of this file ?